# C# Mini Http Server, Knowing when to close a connection

Tags: c#, webserver, tcplistener

I've been coding my own http web server in C# using the TcpListener class. Now before anyone mentions this, I know of the HttpListener, but after using that previously, I.ve had some issues with it due to firewall exceptions and needing to have an admin account etc etc. For my application, its just easier to make a simple, built web server. I've been using a python application to connect to my C# webserver, and send a simple GET request, and receive in return a simple response.

My question is this.. Is the server supposed to close the connection, or the client? I ask because if i close the connection in the server after sending the response, my Python app doesn't always get to read ALL of the response. Instead, a socket error will be thrown "Error 10054, 'Connection reset by peer'". But, if I force the python app to close the connection, I'm not sure how to detect that on my C# server, since C# TcpClient does not contain a disconnect event. So what do i do? How do i know when the connected client has received the full response so i can close the connection?

Currently, this works (with a thread sleep)

```
// Write headers and body to the Socket
        NetworkStream Stream = Client.GetStream();

        // Write Headers
        byte[] Buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Headers);
        Stream.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);

        // Write Response Data if Request method is not HEAD
        if (Request.RequestMethod != HttpRequestMethod.HEAD)
            Stream.Write(BodyByteArr, 0, BodyByteArr.Length);

        Stream.Flush();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        Stream.Close();
        Client.Close();
```

I think that i need a better alternative then Thread.Sleep(), which probably doesn't work either if the client takes more then the sleep time to receive the response (Slow Connection)

Headers Sent to the Http Server:

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: close
```

Headers sent back to client:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: {Now}
Server: MiniHttp-ASPServer
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: {length}
Connection: close

{contents}
```

Comment: What headers are you sending to the client?

Comment: I would guess that this is a content-length problem.  I believe content length is the length of the body only.  One way you can debug this a little is to use a robust client like chrome to see if it handles an improperly formed request (or if it ever finishes handling the request) using the F12 tools.

Comment: Using a web browser, there is no problems at all. Only the python socket has issues with the socket closing before it can read. Thats where the whole "Thread.Sleep" comes into play. IF i remove that sleep, python will get socket errors, otherwise it works... So i imagine im closing the connection too fast?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the Synchronous and Asynchronous Socket samples at h[ttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex.aspx][1]

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex.aspx ?

I think you can work some of the logic into your solution. In the synchronous server example (snippet):

```
       while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming                      connection.
            Socket handler = listener.Accept();
            data = null;

            // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
            while (true) {
                bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec);
                if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Show the data on the console.
            Console.WriteLine( "Text received : {0}", data);

            // Echo the data back to the client.
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            handler.Send(msg);
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }
```

On the client side:

```
         sender.Connect(remoteEP);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                              sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Encode the data string into a byte array.
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");

            // Send the data through the socket.
            int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                                Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec));

            // Release the socket.
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();
```

Comment: Well, This doesn't really answer my question, or help me all to much. I did incorporate the Socket.Shutdown() in my script (I totally didn't know about this method), and that seemed to help just a little bit, but i still received 2 socket errors out of 48 async requests. Getting closer, but not quite :)

Comment: OK. Well you might want to look into the Socket.ReceiveTimeout Property found at: [link] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx Also, I would still encourage you to run the examples in the previous link I  gave you and see if it will give some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from HTTP1.1 RFC:

> If either the client or the server sends the close token in the Connection header, that request becomes the last one for the connection.

So, when your server closes the connection it previously has to answer with a Connection: close header.

I don't know C# and it's TCP client, but there are several reasons a send on a socket may fail. I can't see that you handle any of these before you shutdown your application.

You must retry to send the answer until you are sure that it is read completely.
I think your Connection: close header never reaches your client and thats the reason that is answers with "Connection reset by peer".